How to clip marked area in below image in flutter?
i created chart with custom painter but the problem is i want to set chartbar height fix but the fill color of chart show in entire screen how can i crop upper part of container based on char curves
is possible to cut container same as chart curves
current chart
want to cut marked area
like this
Refrence chart
Chartbar code :
// CustomPainter class to draw a curved chart
class CurvedChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  // Properties to configure the chart
  final List<Map<String, double>> xValues;
  final List<Map<String, double>> yValues;
  final Color? color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final List<Color> gradientColors;
  final List<double> gradientStops;
  final TextStyle labelTextStyle;

  // Constructor
  CurvedChartPainter({
    required this.xValues,
    required this.yValues,
    required this.strokeWidth,
    this.color,
    this.gradientColors = const [
      Color(0x00F63E02),
      Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    ],
    this.gradientStops = const [0.0, 1.0],
    this.labelTextStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
  });

  // The paint method is called when the custom painter needs to paint
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Set up the paint for the chart line
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = color ?? const Color(0xFFF63E02);
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;

    // Set up the paint for the chart fill
    var fillPaint = Paint();
    fillPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    // Set up the paint for the axes
    var axisPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;


    // Create paths for the chart line and fill
    var path = Path();
    var fillPath = Path();

    // Check if there are enough values to draw the chart
    if (xValues.length > 1 && yValues.isNotEmpty) {
      // Calculate some initial values
      final maxValue = yValues.last.values.last;
      final firstValueHeight = size.height * (xValues.first.values.first / maxValue);

      // Initialize the paths with the first point
      path.moveTo(0.0, size.height - firstValueHeight);
      fillPath.moveTo(0.0, size.height);
      fillPath.lineTo(0.0, size.height - firstValueHeight);

      // Calculate the distance between each x value
      final itemXDistance = size.width / (xValues.length - 1);

      // Loop through the x values and draw the chart line and fill
      for (var i = 1; i < xValues.length; i++) {
        final x = itemXDistance * i;
        final valueHeight = size.height - strokeWidth - ((size.height - strokeWidth) * (xValues[i].values.elementAt(0) / maxValue));
        final previousValueHeight = size.height - strokeWidth - ((size.height - strokeWidth) * (xValues[i - 1].values.elementAt(0) / maxValue));

        // Draw a quadratic bezier curve between each point
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
          x - (itemXDistance / 2) - (itemXDistance / 8),
          previousValueHeight,
          x - (itemXDistance / 2),
          valueHeight + ((previousValueHeight - valueHeight) / 2),
        );
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
          x - (itemXDistance / 2) + (itemXDistance / 8),
          valueHeight,
          x,
          valueHeight,
        );

        // Draw the fill path using the same quadratic bezier curves
        fillPath.quadraticBezierTo(
          x - (itemXDistance / 2) - (itemXDistance / 8),
          previousValueHeight,
          x - (itemXDistance / 2),
          valueHeight + ((previousValueHeight - valueHeight) / 2),
        );
        fillPath.quadraticBezierTo(
          x - (itemXDistance / 2) + (itemXDistance / 8),
          valueHeight,
          x,
          valueHeight,
        );
      }

      // Close the fill path
      fillPath.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
      fillPath.close();
    }

    // Create a gradient for the fill
    LinearGradient gradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: gradientColors,
      stops: gradientStops,
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    );
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    fillPaint.shader = gradient.createShader(rect);

    // Draw the fill path with the gradient
    canvas.drawPath(fillPath, fillPaint);

    // Draw the chart line
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

  }

used like this with stack
// Build method to generate the widget tree
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Define the X axis values for the chart
  // String will be text label and double will be value in the Map<String, double>
  final List<Map<String, double>> xValues = [
    {"day 1": 80.0},
    {"day 2": 50.0},
    {"day 3": 30.0},
    {"day 4": 50.0},
    {"day 5": 10.0},
    {"day 6": 0.0},
    {"day 7": 100.0},
  ];

  // Define the Y axis values for the chart
  // String will be text label and double will be value in the Map<String, double>
  final List<Map<String, double>> yValues = [
    {"0": 0.0},
    {"20": 20.0},
    {"40": 40.0},
    {"60": 60.0},
    {"80": 80.0},
    {"100": 100.0},
  ];

  // Define the stroke width for the chart line
  const stroke = 3.0;

  // Return a SizedBox to limit the size of the chart
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: blue2,
       
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
        // Use CustomPaint to draw the curved chart
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CurvedChartPainter(
            color: blue5,
            // Set the color of the chart line
            yValues: yValues,
            // Pass the Y axis values
            strokeWidth: stroke,
            // Set the stroke width
            xValues: xValues,
            // Pass the X axis values
            gradientStops: [0.22, 063],
            gradientColors: [
              // Define the gradient colors for the chart fill
              calenderLinearGradient2.withOpacity(0.46),
              blue1.withOpacity(0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}


yap it is possible, but it seems you are using Container to to cover the bottom part

@Md. Yeasin Sheikh can you explain how to do that or code snippet please

You can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/combine.html
